# ACCT is missing in transaction response in Payflow Pro

Tags: c#, asp.net, payflowpro

From Payflow Pro [documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_RecurringBilling_Guide.pdf).

Expected results are as follow:

**Inquiry Request:**

```
TRXTYPE=R&TENDER=C&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=Acme&USER=Acme&PWD=a1b2c3d4&ACTION=I&ORIGPROFILEID=RP000000001234
```

**Inquiry Resopnse:**

```
RESULT=0&RPREF=RJL500026884&PROFILEID=RP0000000001&STATUS=ACTIVE&PROFILENAME=test&START=01012005&TERM=12&NEXTPAYMENT=01012005&END=03192005&PAYPERIOD=WEEK&AMT=1.00&ACCT=4012XXXXXXXX1881&EXPDATE=0203&PAYMENTSLEFT=12&AGGREGATEAMT=0.00&AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT=0.00&MAXFAILPAYMENTS=0&NUMFAILPAYMENTS=0&RETRYNUMDAYS=0
```

However, this is what I am getting this.

**Inquiry Request:**

```
 TRXTYPE[1]=R&USER[10]=MyPayFlowUserName&VENDOR[10]=TheFarmAUD&PARTNER[3]=VSA&PWD[9]=XXXXXXXXX&ACTION[1]=I&RETRYNUMDAYS[1]=0&ORIGPROFILEID[12]=RP00000011111&PAYMENTHISTORY[1]=YRequestId=RP000011111
```

**Inquiry Resopnse:**

```
RESULT=0&RPREF=RTF5A6130634&PROFILEID=RP00000011111&P_PNREF1=VPFRA23661B4&P_TRANSTIME1=04-Dec-13 04:59 AM&P_RESULT1=0&P_TENDER1=C&P_AMT1=45.95&P_TRANSTATE1=8&P_PNREF2=VDJRB5B20D68&P_TRANSTIME2=04-Jan-14 04:51 AM&P_RESULT2=0&P_TENDER2=C&P_AMT2=4.95&P_TRANSTATE2=8&P_PNREF3=VTYRB7599E12&P_TRANSTIME3=04-Feb-14 04:59 AM&P_RESULT3=0&P_TENDER3=C&P_AMT3=4.95&P_TRANSTATE3=8&DUPLICATE=1"
```

Some information, such as EXPDATE and ACCT are missing in my result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my request contained "PAYMENTHISTORY[1]=Y" which means I requested the transaction history of the profile, to request the status of a profile which contains "EXPDATE and ACCT", after removing "PAYMENTHISTORY[1]=Y" from my request, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Payflow does not pass back EXPDATE and ACCT for security. So you are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: How would I allow our customer to update their credit cards then? We need to show at least some last digits of currently active credit card, eg: XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-456

Comment: You would modify the profile using the profile ID. The CC number and exp date are stored in the backend of Payflow. Page 23 of the guide https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf shows you examples and the required parameters to pass when updating the profile with a new card number or exp date.